# Can anybody explain "rebuilding cycle" for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does this sentence mean "U.S. banks seem to be clearly ending with the eight-year crisis cycle or ending with rebuilding cycle" OR "U.S. banks seem to be clearly ending with the eight-year crisis cycle or U.S. banks seem to be clearly rebuilding cycle"?

"When we look at the general landscape, I would say **U.S. banks seem to be clearly ending with the eight-year crisis cycle or rebuilding cycle**. We've seen signs that U.S. banks are truly turning the page," David Benamou, managing partner at Axiom Alternative Investments, told CNBC on Tuesday.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/18/us-banks-are-now-truly-turning-the-page-asset-manager-says.html

Answer (score 1):

> When we look at the general landscape, I would say U.S. banks seem to be clearly ending with the eight-year crisis cycle or rebuilding cycle.

Here, in your example, applies the definition #2 of or from [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/or):

> **or**:
>
> 2. Used to indicate a synonymous or equivalent expression: acrophobia, or fear of great heights.

Consequently **the eight-year crisis cycle** is the same as **rebuilding cycle**.

Comment: As a side note, this use of **ending with** sounds odd to me. The complement of **end with** is a *result*.  "Some marriages end with *divorce*".    The collocation is a variant of **end in**.  Here, however, it is used to mean "are parting ways with {something}".  If this is a common use, I have never seen it before, though I've heard **ending *it* with {someone}** many times, as it is a common idiom.

Comment: I see, I think I'm getting your point, @TRomano.

Comment: @TRomano something like "the reign of X bank seems to be clearly ending with ..." would work, though I agree that this instance sounds weird.